# Customize panel of DirectionsRenderer with custom css

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I use DirectionsService in  Google Maps API and render the result using DirectionsRenderer. I use setPanel() function and the direction instructions are successfully rendered. However, is there any way that I can customize the layout and design with my own css files?

I'm still stuck between either using JSON response or customize the HTML class provided by DirectionsRenderer

[The example of class name provided by DirectionsRenderer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0BCs.jpg)

Comment: Don't use the renderer. Get the API response and use anything you need from there.

Comment: @MrUpsidown, so it is better to use JSON response to fill in HTML elements rather than customize the default classes provided by DirectionsRenderer(eg: adp-list, atp-list as shown above)?

Comment: Definitely yes. HTML structure and CSS classes are not documented and could change at any point without notice (with a new API version, etc.). I would either use it as it is, or build it from scratch from the API response.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations!~ Now I get a clear view on what I want to do.